# Can I always extend an inner product from a real to a complex vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a vector space over the real numbers with finite dimension. Let
 <,> : VxV -> R be an inner product on V. Let W be the same vector space V, but now considered as a vector space over the complex numbers. Is it always possible to define a new inner product <,>_2 : WxW -> C that coincides with <,> on V? Is it uniquely determined ?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean. Typically, an inner product takes a pair of elements from a vector space $V$ and casts it to the underlying field: $\langle\ \cdot , \cdot \rangle : V \times V \to F$.

Comment: thank you. Just corrected that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An inner product is a map to the ground field, not the space itself. Given an inner product $(\cdot, \cdot):V\times V\to \mathbb{R}$, we can extend it to $W = V\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$ by setting $(v\otimes z, v'\otimes z') = z\overline{z}' (v, v')$. Note that this new product is defined over $\mathbb{C}$, though, not $\mathbb{R}$.